# Webpack - How to replace file reference based on environment?

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) tool, environment files are present. You can specify them in your config file, like:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Anywhere in your project where you want to use the environment variables, all you have to do is include the base `environment.ts` file. Then, based on the build environment you can pass e.g. using `ng build --prod`, the file reference may change (so for `prod`, it will use `environment.prod.ts` instead of `environment.ts`).

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality through Webpack configuration, but can't figure out how to achieve this.

Anyone who can give an example on how to configure such dynamic file reference based on environments in Webpack?

Thanks!

Comment: have you had any success with it? I'm also interested in a solution.